# Matlab histc with vector bins

Tags: matlab, histogram, vectorization

If I have two matrices A and B of size [m x n] and [p x n], and I want to find the counts of the number of times each row of B appears in A, for example:

```
>> A = rand(5,3)

A =

    0.1419    0.6557    0.7577
    0.4218    0.0357    0.7431
    0.9157    0.8491    0.3922
    0.7922    0.9340    0.6555
    0.9595    0.6787    0.1712

>> B = [A(2,:); A(1,:); A(2,:); A(3,:); A(3,:); A(4,:); A(5,:)] 

B =

    0.4218    0.0357    0.7431
    0.1419    0.6557    0.7577
    0.4218    0.0357    0.7431
    0.9157    0.8491    0.3922
    0.9157    0.8491    0.3922
    0.7922    0.9340    0.6555
    0.9595    0.6787    0.1712
```

with the answer in this case being

```
ans =

     1     2     2     1     1
```

although unlike this example, in general m >> p

If A and B were vectors matlab's histc would do the job, but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent if the bins are vectors.

Currently I do it by:

```
for i=1:length(B)
    indices(i) = find(abs(A/B(i,:)-1) < 1e-15); 
    % division requires a tolerance due to numerical issues
end
histc(indices, 1:size(A,1))

ans =

     1     2     2     1     1
```

but since I have many such matrices B, and both A and B are large, this is horribly slow. Any ideas how to improve on this?

EDIT:

Looking at the methods so far, I have the following data:

```
A                    7871139x3                188907336  double                       
B                        902x3                    21648  double
```

To make things quicker I'm just going to use the first 10 rows of B

```
B = B(1:10,:);
```

Note that for the full application I (currently) have >10^4 of such matrices (this will eventually be >10^6 ....)

My first method:

```
tic, C = get_vector_index(A,B); toc
Elapsed time is 36.630107 seconds.
```

bdecaf's method (can be reduced to ~25 seconds by removing the `if` statement and using L1 distance instead of L2 distance)

```
>> tic, C1 = get_vector_index(A,B); toc
Elapsed time is 28.957243 seconds.
>> isequal(C, C1) 

ans =

     1
```

oli's pdist2 method

```
>> tic, C2 = get_vector_index(A,B); toc
Elapsed time is 7.244965 seconds.

>> isequal(C,C2)

ans =

     1
```

oli's normalisation method

```
>> tic, C3 = get_vector_index(A,B); toc
Elapsed time is 3.756682 seconds.

>> isequal(C,C3)

ans =

     1
```

Finally I came up with another method, where I search the first column, then I search the second column within the hits of the first column, recursing until the columns are exhausted. This is the fastest so far ....

```
N = size(A,2);
loc = zeros(size(B,1),1);
for i=1:size(B,1)
    idx{1} = find(A(:,1)==B(i,1));
    for k=2:N, 
        idx{k} = idx{k-1}(find(A(idx{k-1},k)==B(i,k))); 
    end
    loc(i) = idx{end};
end
C = histc(loc, 1:size(A,1));
```

which results in:

```
>> tic, C4 = get_vector_index(A,B); toc
Elapsed time is 1.314370 seconds.

>> isequal(C, C4)

ans =

     1
```

Also note that using `intersect` is much slower:

```
>> tic, [~,IA] = intersect(A,B,'rows'); C5 = histc(IA,1:size(A,1)); toc
Elapsed time is 44.392593 seconds.

>> isequal(C,C5)

ans = 

    1
```

Comment: By the way I realise that the matrix division in my current method is fallible too - it is (just about) possible to get a spurious false positive, but it would generate an error as there can only be one match for each vector of B in A in all the cases I have.

Comment: Just a technicallity - the code as you put it will only work if all rows in B have a row in A. Also if there are two nearly identical rows in A it will be problematic. The behaviour is also different to histc. `histc` sorts into the *nearest* bin - you made it when it is exactly in the bin.

Comment: Also be carefull using length - it will always return the largest size. So if `p<n` there will be trouble.

Comment: Sorry yes the length(B) should be size(B,1) ... that crept in when I was creating the example.

Comment: AS for the previous one, yes my description was maybe lacking, as in my case all rows in B do have a row in A - it's just that histc will solve my problem in the 1-D case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually put this solution as an edit in the question, but for the sake of accepting an answer I'll put the solution in here too:

```
N = size(A,2);
loc = zeros(size(B,1),1);
for i=1:size(B,1)
    idx{1} = find(A(:,1)==B(i,1));
    for k=2:N, 
        idx{k} = idx{k-1}(find(A(idx{k-1},k)==B(i,k))); 
    end
    loc(i) = idx{end};
end
C = histc(loc, 1:size(A,1));
```

which results in:

```
>> tic, C4 = get_vector_index(A,B); toc
Elapsed time is 1.314370 seconds.

>> isequal(C, C4)

ans =

     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could normalize them such that you check that their dot product is `1`

```
A = rand(5,3);
B = [A(2,:); A(1,:); A(2,:); A(3,:); A(3,:); A(4,:); A(5,:)];
A2=bsxfun(@times,A,1./sqrt(sum(A.^2,2))); %%% normalize A
B2=bsxfun(@times,B,1./sqrt(sum(B.^2,2))) %%% normalize B
sum(A2*B2'>1-10e-9,2) %%% check that the dotproduct is close to 1

ans =

     1
     2
     2
     1
     1
```

If you need something even faster but approximated, I recommand you to use the flann library, which is for fast approximated nearest neighbor:

http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~mariusm/index.php/FLANN/FLANN

Comment: I quite like this approach, but the matrix multiplication doesn't fit in memory (e.g. A is 7871139x3  and B is 903x3)

Comment: I had a look at FLANN too, but I don't think I can install it as I don't have a sudoers account - to compile from source requires cmake (which isn't installed, and the installation of that just bombs out for me, presumably because I'm not a sudoer), and currently their prebuilt libraries are ubuntu/debian only (server is Red Hat)

Comment: If you have linux 64 bits, I can send you my compiled version.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve it like this:

```
indices = zeros(size(A,1),1);
for i=1:size(B,1)
    distances = sum( ( repmat(B(i,:),size(A,1),1)-A ).^2 ,2);
    [md,im]=min(distances);
    if md < 1e-9
      indices(im) = indices(im)+1;
    end
end
```

if you remove the if it will just sort into the nearest bin.

Comment: Slightly slower than method from @oli

Answer (score 1):

Actually, a simpler way of doing that is:

```
sum(10e-9>pdist2(A',B'),2)
```

it compute all pairwise distances and threshhold and count.